# Javascript - adding comma automatically to input field

Tags: javascript, function, input

I will post the part of a function that is adding numbers that are clicked into selected input field.

So, I need to separate it with a comma (,). I tried some of the examples but it seems not to be working on the function that I wrote.

```
 var rowRange = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');

var $cart = $('#seats'),
    $counter = $('#counter'),
    sc = $('#seat-map').seatCharts({
    map: [
        'aaaaa__aaaaa',
        'aaaaa__aaaaa'
    ],

    naming : {
        top : false,
        getLabel : function (character, row, column) {
            return rowRange[row - 1].toUpperCase() + column;
        },
    },

    click: function () {
        if (this.status() === 'available') {

            $('#seats').split(",")
                 .attr('id', 'cart-item-'+this.settings.id)
                 .val(this.settings.label)
                 .appendTo($cart);

            $counter.text(sc.find('selected').length+1);

            return 'selected';
    });
});
```

Seat is a input field where comma needs to be added after every click on any number.

> .split(",")

when I remove this part the code works like it should, but without adding comma.

Comment: Can you return a full example of your code? That will help us help you.

Comment: Sure. I updated the post.

Comment: Your code itself is not valid javascript, that is causing some errors. Instead of separating variables with the comma `,`, can you end each variable declaration with a semicolon `;` instead? Your `.seatCharts` code is also not closed properly.

Comment: @Zac The code itself is of course valid JS. I really don't know what you are talking about, declaring multiple variables at once by separating them with comma is perfectly valid.

Comment: I cuted out beginning and the end because it was unnecessary. It works. Problem is with separating..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.split()` doesn't work on jquery objects. Instead use it on the values in your select.

Here is an example on how it could work.

```js
$selected = $('#selected');
$(".seat").on("click", function() {
  const cur = $selected.val();
  const valToInsert = $(this).text();
  $selected.val(cur.length === 0 ? valToInsert : cur.split(',').concat(valToInsert).join(','));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="selected">

<button class="seat">a</button>
```